# Why does the status bar on Android take up so much space?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

From one day to another the status bar in the emulator seems much larger in height. I can't remember that I have changed anything. How can I remove the empty space between status bar and action bar?

[image]

The status bar is red so you can see it's real height. I really don't know where the blank space comes from.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a [tall notch](https://medium.com/@hiteshdhamshaniya.wvmagic/notch-android-emulator-with-p-e9b3556d9d5e)? Try [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector).

Comment: Have you phrases your emulator operative system? And, does this problem appear on real devices?

Comment: If this is occurring in just one screen, can you show a copy of the xml for the layout.